# Remove "#" from URL in Vue Router (Vue.js 2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-router

My current URL is like `domain/main.html#/` => This loads my home page

I want my URL to be free from '#' i.e. `domain/main.html/`

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes,
)}
```

I read articles and answers on StackOverflow, youtube, etc and they all said the same thing that mode: 'history' would solve the issue and yes it does but my routes are not working. All of them are showing => `Cannot GET domain/main.html/`

I dug a little more and it says to catch the not found fallback using

```
{ path: '*', redirect: '/' }
```

I tried this but still not working.

```
{ path: '*', redirect: '/' }
```

but this time it opens my page but images and scripts are not loading this time, and if I reload again I get the same `Cannot GET Error`.

Any Help to solve this issue would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML file should be named **index.html**, so you have "domain.com/" and not "domain.com/main.html".

If you want to continue to use main.html as the HTML file name, you should config your server to respond always with that file.

But I suggest you rename the HTML file to **index.html**

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you please refer me to some article / way to configure my server accordingly because I want to use main.html as the HTML file name.

Comment: https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations  This I guess can help you. Just change index.html to main.html and should work.